# User Defined Functions in Automation Addin behave differently Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007, user-defined-functions, shim

I have created an automation addin in C# .NET and have a shim dll for it. The 
shim dll has all the User Defined methods in it that calls the appropriate 
methods in the .NET assembly.

The problem that I am facing is related to Excel 2007.

In Excel 2003,
1. Add a new shape to a worksheet
2. Insert >> Function >> SUM. The Function arguments dialog comes up
3. click on the newly inserted shape instead of a cell
Note: Nothing happens and no cell value is entered automatically in the 
argument box

Now in Excel 2007,
1. Insert a new shape
2. Formulas Ribbon Tab >> Insert Function >> SUM. Function Arguments dialog 
comes up
3. Click on the newly inserted shape
Note that now an error dialog is displayed saying "The formula you typed 
contains an error"

**This dialog comes up for a predefined function (SUM). If I select my 
function from the list in-place of SUM, the error dialog is not displayed and 
the Function Argument dialog just vanishes. The cell then shows an error 
smarttag.**

Is there something that needs to be put into the SHIM dll for each function? 
Like an attribute or something that will display this error dialog. OR maybe 
some special value that is returned by the method to tell that the argument 
has generated an error.

The function defined in the COM shim are like:

```
STDMETHOD(GetArea)(MyExcelAddIn::Range *r, double *pRetVal)
{
   return m_pMyUDF->GetArea(r, pRetVal);
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that your function takes object as argument as against a specific type such as Range. Is that the case?

Comment: This is how the methods are declared. This method returns a "TRUE" or "FALSE" based on the whether the selected cell is valid.

STDMETHOD(IsValid)(MyAddIn::Range *r, BSTR *pRetVal)
{
   return m_pMyExcelUDF->IsValid(r, pRetVal);
}

Are there any attributes for UDF methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I contacted Microsoft and they confirmed that this is a bug in the Excel product. I will post the bug link when I get it from them.**